# Permanent window with list of opened buffers

Tags: window-splitting

Is there some mode where emacs fixes a small window with a list of opened buffers? This is what simpler editors have (kate,gedit,etc).

Here's an example from Kate:

[image]

In the left window there is a list of opened files. This is rather independent from the main editing window, while being connected. Some examples: I can maximize the whole set, it doesn't disappear if I split/unsplit the main editing windows.

(Edited for clarity)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>M-x speedbar</kbd> and typing <kbd>b</kbd> (buffer display mode).  This gives you a narrow dedicated frame with the required information.

Comment: Can I have it together with the main window? So that I don't have to handle two separate windows? For instance if I maximize the main edit window, the speedbar disappears.

Comment: @Fernando César: I don't think so, unfortunately.

Comment: Try srspeedbar for a separate window rather than frame.

Comment: @Dan: How would you do that?

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm answered below about sr-speedbar

Answer (score 3):

To include the speedbar in the main frame, use the **sr-speedbar** library - <kbd>M-x package-list-packages</kbd>, look for sr-speedbar, then hit <kbd>i</kbd> then <kbd>x</kbd> to install it.

To turn it on and off, call `sr-speedbar-toggle` - then you can bind it to a convenient key in your .emacs file, e.g.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-1") 'sr-speedbar-toggle)
```

With a little tweaking you can get it over on the left side of the screen and looking a little nicer. Try <kbd>M-x customize-apropos</kbd> sr-speedbar and <kbd>M-x customize-apropos</kbd> speedbar to set various options.

There's a bit more info on the Emacs Wiki - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar.

It would be great if these libraries could be merged and included in Emacs someday.

Comment: I do like sr-speedbar, just what I was looking for, just one little nit. I wish when I select the buffer and hit enter the window would go away, like sr-speedbar-close was called. Could I do this with defadvise or something?

Comment: Nevermind, got it: (advice-add 'speedbar-edit-line :after #'sr-speedbar-close)

Answer (score 2):

The command to open the list of buffers that you want is `list-buffers`. It is bound to `C-x C-b` by default.

Put this in your init file, or use `M-x customize-option RET special-display-buffer-names` to customize the variable to include an entry for buffer `*Buffer List*`:

```el
(add-to-list 'special-display-buffer-names "*Buffer List*")
```

Then the buffer list will be in its own, dedicated frame.

Comment: Yes, I know `list-buffers`, but is not really adapted to a small column. By your answer I guess what I was thinking doesn't exits.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. In particular it is unclear what you mean by "*I can ... open a buffer list ....*" Please *show your code* (what you've tried), what you expect/want, and how what you have tried so far differs from that. Also, presumably you do not mean "*opened buffers*" in your title and description, but rather a "*list of names of* opened buffers". If so, please edit to make this clear.

Comment: Hy @Drew. I edited the question. I hope it's more clear what I was asking. I'm not developing anything, I was just asking if emacs has an option I see often in other editors.